# django admin panel image field produces wrong path to image

Tags: django

I have an image field that uploads to the media/ directory. In the django admin panel, it links to admin/api/character/2/change/media/image.jpg, instead of media/image.jpg. How do I correct this?

edit: the html are all default django admin templates. in fact, nothing about this is special. the imagefield is straight django. the admin template is straight django. the implementation is all straight django.
settings.py looks like this

```py
 13 import os
 14 
 16 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
 17 
 23 from loot_tracker.secrets import secrets
 24 SECRET_KEY = secrets['secret_key']
 25 
 27 DEBUG = True
 28 
 29 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]
 33 
 34 INSTALLED_APPS = [
 35     'jet.dashboard',
 36     'jet',
 37     'django.contrib.admin',
 38     'django.contrib.auth',
 39     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 40     'django.contrib.sessions',
 41     'django.contrib.messages',
 42     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 43 
 44     'django_extensions',
 45     'django_filters',
 46     'django_user_agents',
 47     'rest_framework',
 48     'tracking_analyzer',
 49 
 50     'api',
 51 ]
 52 
 53 MIDDLEWARE = [
 54     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 55     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 56     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 57     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 58     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 59     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 60     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 61 ]
 62 
 63 ROOT_URLCONF = 'loot_tracker.urls'
 64 
 65 TEMPLATES = [
 66     {
 67         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
 68         'DIRS': [],
 69         'APP_DIRS': True,
 70         'OPTIONS': {
 71             'context_processors': [
 72                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
 73                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
 74                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
 75                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
 76             ],
 77         },
 78     },
 79 ]
 80 
 81 WSGI_APPLICATION = 'loot_tracker.wsgi.application'
 82 
 87 DATABASES = {
 88         'default': {
 89         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
 90         'NAME': 'postgres',
 91         'USER': 'postgres',
 92         'PASSWORD': secrets['db_pass'],
 93         'HOST': 'db',
 94         'PORT': '',
 95     }
 96 }
 97 
102 AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
103     {
104         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
105     },
106     {
107         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
108     },
109     {
110         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
111     },
112     {
113         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
114     },
115 ]
120 
121 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
122 
123 TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
124 
125 USE_I18N = True
126 
127 USE_L10N = True
128 
129 USE_TZ = True
134 
135 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
136 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public')
137 
138 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
139     'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
140     'PAGE_SIZE': 50
141 }
142 
143 CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
145 
146 GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip/')
147 
148 CLIENT_ID = secrets['client_id']
149 CLIENT_SECRET = secrets['client_secret']
~
```

models.py, note the avatar field.

```py
  8 class Character(models.Model):
  9     name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
 10     level = models.IntegerField(default=2)
 11     game_class = models.CharField(max_length=20)
 12     guild = models.ForeignKey('Guild', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
 13     avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', default='media/tyrone.jpg')
```

admin.py for brevity

```py
  9 class CharacterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 10     search_fields = ('name', 'game_class', 'level')
 11 admin.site.register(Character, CharacterAdmin)
```

Comment: can you put your code to understand more but I guess that you problem you need just add a .url for example image.url

Comment: There's no way of telling this without looking at some code. Show us some relevant HTML files as well as settings.py

Comment: you have to set MEDIA ROOT and MEDIA URL path where you will be storing your images https://overiq.com/django-1-10/handling-media-files-in-django/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You serve the django admin through `mysite.com/admin/`
- You have a directory in your server named `.../media/`  where files are uploaded correctly
- These files in `.../media/` are correctly served through the URL `mysite.com/media/` (e.g. If you manually type `mysite.com/media/myfile.jpg` in your browser you get the file `.../media/myfile.jpg` in your server)
- You are in `mysite.com/admin/api/character/2/change/` and you have a file field there where you can upload files (and you see them in your server when uploading)

Issue:

- The URL/link of the file being presented by the Django admin AFTER uploading is `mysite.com/admin/api/character/2/change/media/image.jpg`, instead of `mysite.com/media/image.jpg`

Solution:

- In the settings of your Django app, define the setting `MEDIA_URL` so Django knows where to serve the media files from. Since you haven't defined the setting, it defaults to `MEDIA_URL=''`, so in effect it only appends the file's path to the current URL.

Side Note:

- The `upload_to` parameter in `FileField` refers to the directory INSIDE the storage you are using. In this case, if you are uploading files to a folder in your server named `/home/mysite/media/`, and you set `upload_to='media/'`, all files uploaded to that field will be uploaded to `/home/mysite/media/media/`.